# Перебрать массив

Tags: javascript

```
[
{
    "interval": {
        "begin": "2023-09-20",
        "end": "2023-09-21"
    },
    "views": 2163,
    "clicks": 110,
    "ctr": 5.09,
    "cpc": 12.52,
    "sum": 1377.44,
    "atbs": 4,
    "orders": 0,
    "cr": 0,
    "shks": 0,
    "sum_price": 0,
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2023-09-20T03:00:00+03:00",
            "views": 1289,
            "clicks": 59,
            "ctr": 4.58,
            "cpc": 13.85,
            "sum": 816.89,
            "atbs": 3,
            "orders": 0,
            "cr": 0,
            "shks": 0,
            "sum_price": 0,
            "apps": [
                {
                    "views": 95,
                    "clicks": 3,
                    "ctr": 3.16,
                    "cpc": 19.8,
                    "sum": 59.39,
                    "atbs": 1,
                    "orders": 0,
                    "cr": 0,
                    "shks": 0,
                    "sum_price": 0,
                    "nm": [
                        {
                            "views": 50,
                            "clicks": 2,
                            "ctr": 4,
                            "cpc": 15.76,
                            "sum": 31.51,
                            "atbs": 1,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467195
                        },
                        {
                            "views": 45,
                            "clicks": 1,
                            "ctr": 2.22,
                            "cpc": 27.88,
                            "sum": 27.88,
                            "atbs": 0,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467194
                        }
                    ],
                    "appType": 1
                },
                {
                    "views": 849,
                    "clicks": 36,
                    "ctr": 4.24,
                    "cpc": 14.9,
                    "sum": 536.31,
                    "atbs": 1,
                    "orders": 0,
                    "cr": 0,
                    "shks": 0,
                    "sum_price": 0,
                    "nm": [
                        {
                            "views": 317,
                            "clicks": 20,
                            "ctr": 6.31,
                            "cpc": 10.21,
                            "sum": 204.22,
                            "atbs": 1,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467194
                        },
                        {
                            "views": 532,
                            "clicks": 16,
                            "ctr": 3.01,
                            "cpc": 20.76,
                            "sum": 332.09,
                            "atbs": 0,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467195
                        }
                    ],
                    "appType": 32
                },
                {
                    "views": 345,
                    "clicks": 20,
                    "ctr": 5.8,
                    "cpc": 11.06,
                    "sum": 221.19,
                    "atbs": 1,
                    "orders": 0,
                    "cr": 0,
                    "shks": 0,
                    "sum_price": 0,
                    "nm": [
                        {
                            "views": 153,
                            "clicks": 10,
                            "ctr": 6.54,
                            "cpc": 9.88,
                            "sum": 98.78,
                            "atbs": 1,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467194
                        },
                        {
                            "views": 192,
                            "clicks": 10,
                            "ctr": 5.21,
                            "cpc": 12.24,
                            "sum": 122.41,
                            "atbs": 0,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467195
                        }
                    ],
                    "appType": 64
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-09-21T03:00:00+03:00",
            "views": 874,
            "clicks": 51,
            "ctr": 0.01,
            "cpc": 10.99,
            "sum": 560.55,
            "atbs": 1,
            "orders": 0,
            "cr": 0,
            "shks": 0,
            "sum_price": 0,
            "apps": [
                {
                    "views": 56,
                    "clicks": 0,
                    "ctr": 0,
                    "cpc": 0,
                    "sum": 33.94,
                    "atbs": 0,
                    "orders": 0,
                    "cr": 0,
                    "shks": 0,
                    "sum_price": 0,
                    "nm": [
                        {
                            "views": 38,
                            "clicks": 0,
                            "ctr": 0,
                            "cpc": 0,
                            "sum": 23.03,
                            "atbs": 0,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467195
                        },
                        {
                            "views": 18,
                            "clicks": 0,
                            "ctr": 0,
                            "cpc": 0,
                            "sum": 10.91,
                            "atbs": 0,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467194
                        }
                    ],
                    "appType": 1
                },
                {
                    "views": 607,
                    "clicks": 35,
                    "ctr": 5.77,
                    "cpc": 11.12,
                    "sum": 389.05,
                    "atbs": 1,
                    "orders": 0,
                    "cr": 0,
                    "shks": 0,
                    "sum_price": 0,
                    "nm": [
                        {
                            "views": 198,
                            "clicks": 16,
                            "ctr": 8.08,
                            "cpc": 8.11,
                            "sum": 129.68,
                            "atbs": 0,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467194
                        },
                        {
                            "views": 409,
                            "clicks": 19,
                            "ctr": 4.65,
                            "cpc": 13.65,
                            "sum": 259.37,
                            "atbs": 1,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467195
                        }
                    ],
                    "appType": 32
                },
                {
                    "views": 211,
                    "clicks": 16,
                    "ctr": 7.58,
                    "cpc": 0.01,
                    "sum": 0.14,
                    "atbs": 0,
                    "orders": 0,
                    "cr": 0,
                    "shks": 0,
                    "sum_price": 0,
                    "nm": [
                        {
                            "views": 102,
                            "clicks": 8,
                            "ctr": 7.84,
                            "cpc": 8.33,
                            "sum": 66.66,
                            "atbs": 0,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467194
                        },
                        {
                            "views": 109,
                            "clicks": 8,
                            "ctr": 7.34,
                            "cpc": 8.86,
                            "sum": 70.9,
                            "atbs": 0,
                            "orders": 0,
                            "cr": 0,
                            "shks": 0,
                            "sum_price": 0,
                            "name": "Пуховик зимний с капюшоном стеганый",
                            "nmId": 175467195
                        }
                    ],
                    "appType": 64
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "advertId": 9721902
}]
```

Ребята привет подскажите как из этого массива получить вот такое:

```
[advertId, date, nmId, views, clicks]
```

где views, clicks сумарно на эту дату и nmId. Будет того формата:

```
["9721902", "2023-09-20T03:00:00+03:00", "175467194", "515", "31" ],
["9721902", "2023-09-20T03:00:00+03:00", "175467195", "774", "28" ],
["9721902", "2023-09-21T03:00:00+03:00", "175467194", "318", "24" ],
["9721902", "2023-09-21T03:00:00+03:00", "175467195", "556", "27" ]


const result = {};

data.days.forEach(day => {
  day.apps.forEach(app => {
    app.nm.forEach(nm => {
      const { nmId, views, clicks } = nm;
      if (!result[nmId]) {
        result[nmId] = { views, clicks };
      } else {
        result[nmId].views += views;
        result[nmId].clicks += clicks;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Что вы пробовали, что не получилось? С чем возникли сложности?

Comment: как прислать сюда скрипт?)

Comment: Скопировать скрипт и вставить в вопрос

Comment: Добавил что у меня

Comment: Это скрипт из предыдущего ответа под другую задачу.

Comment: Да я пыталься сделать так в day.apps.forEach((key, app)  далее result[key][nmId]